# QGIS3 crashes after exporting the second map in a for loop

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I wrote a python script to produce a few maps automatically. I only have one layer, after the map production I change the style by loading a .qml-file and export the next map, and so on.
I have 7 different .qml-files. They all work, but after two maps, QGIS crashes. It doesn't matter which style-files I use, only the amount makes a difference, after 2 times the crash comes.
Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

file_path ='/home/.../legends/'
source_dir = Path(file_path)
    files = source_dir.iterdir()


for file in files:
    name = str(file)[len(file_path):]
    name_index = name.index('.')
    name=name[:name_index]
       
   
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
    layout.initializeDefaults()
    layout.setName(name)
    project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)

    layer_list = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
    layer = layer_list[0]


# change style:
   layer.loadNamedStyle(str(file))
   layer.triggerRepaint()
   print('layout geändert')

#map:
   map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
   map1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(55,35, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
   map1.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(240, 240, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
   map1.setExtent(layer.extent())
   map1.setLayers([layer])
   map1.setScale(10000000)
   layout.addLayoutItem(map1)

  map1.storeCurrentLayerStyles()
  map1.setKeepLayerSet(True)
  map1.setKeepLayerStyles(True)

# title:

  title = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
  name_title = name.replace("_", " ")
  title.setText(name_title)
  title.setFont(QFont('Arial', 24))
  title.adjustSizeToText()
  layout.addLayoutItem(title)
  title.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

# legend:
  legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)

  layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
  layerTree.addLayer(layer)
  legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)
  layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
  legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 40, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

# scalebar:
  scalebar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
  scalebar.setStyle('Line Ticks Up')
  scalebar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers)
  scalebar.setNumberOfSegments(2)
  scalebar.setNumberOfSegmentsLeft(0)
  scalebar.setUnitsPerSegment(250)
  scalebar.setLinkedMap(map1)
  scalebar.setUnitLabel('km')
  scalebar.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14))
  scalebar.update()
  layout.addLayoutItem(scalebar)
  scalebar.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(200, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
  print('scalebar')
  manager = project.layoutManager()
  layout = manager.layoutByName(name)
  exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
  fn = '/home/.../maps/'+name+'.pdf'
  exporter.exportToPdf(fn, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Is there a kind of a memory-problem?

Comment: Do you know at which step of the script does the crash happen?

Comment: during changing the style the third time

Comment: Maybe you can try a few things to have a better overview of where the problem is: 
1) Look into the result of the ```loadNamedStyle()``` function (e.g., ```tpl_result = layer.loadNamedStyle(str(file))```); 2) clear the content of the ```QgsLayoutManager``` before using it again (e.g., ```project.layoutManager().clear(), project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)```); 3) (unrelated to the specific issue): it should be possible to bring the selection of the layer outside of the loop; 4) the path module offers nice functionalities to retrieve the name from the full path.